# Why isn't it recommended to use bare HTTP status codes in a response?

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, http-status-codes

According to the [documentation for Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/), "using bare status codes in your responses isn't recommended". They recommend instead using the objects from the `status` module (e.g. `status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND`). My question is, where does this recommendation come from? I wasn't able to find any kind of 'official' source for this recommendation.

Comment: Probably just because of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation comes from that document but it's based on concepts like avoiding [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

With the way these statuses are named in Django Rest Framework ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/status.py#L30)) makes it easier for the developer reading the code to understand and remember what the code represents rather than having to remember or double check what each number refers to.